# onTouchevent() problem android

Tags: android, view, touch-event

when i run the code below everything works fine,it's a simple app with three balls that you can move around...

```
public class dragndrop extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       private ColorBall[] colorballs = new ColorBall[3]; // array that holds the balls
       private static final String TAG="MyTAG";
       DrawView myView;
       private int balID = 0; // variable to know what ball is being dragged
       int X;
       int Y;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Point point1 = new Point();
            point1.x = 50;
            point1.y = 20;
            Point point2 = new Point();
            point2.x = 100;
            point2.y = 20;
            Point point3 = new Point();
            point3.x = 150;
            point3.y = 20;


            // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
            colorballs[0] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_groen, point1);
            colorballs[1] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_rood, point2);
            colorballs[2] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_blauw, point3);
            myView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }


    public class DrawView extends View {


        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true); //necessary for getting the touch events

            // setting the start point for the balls


        }

        // the method that draws the balls
        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            //draw the balls on the canvas
            for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
              }

        }



       // events when touching the screen
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

            X = (int)event.getX(); 
            Y = (int)event.getY(); 

            switch (eventaction ) { 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on a ball
                balID = 0;
                for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"inside action down inside for coords:"+X+" coords: "+Y);
                    Log.d(TAG,"ball coords:"+ball.getX()+" coords: "+ball.getY());

                    int x =X;
                    int y =Y;
                    Log.d(TAG,"lalalalalala"+x+" coords: "+y);



                    if (x > ball.getX() && x < ball.getX()+50 && y > ball.getY() && y < ball.getY()+50){//if (X > ball.getX() && X < ball.getX()+50 && Y > ball.getY() && Y < ball.getY()+50){
                        Log.d(TAG,"inside ball coords!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:"+ball.getX()+" coords: "+ball.getY());
                        balID = ball.getID();


                        break;
                    }
                  }

                 break; 


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
                // move the balls the same as the finger
                if (balID > 0) {
                    colorballs[balID-1].setX(X-25);
                    colorballs[balID-1].setY(Y-25);
                }

                break; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

                 break; 
            } 
            // redraw the canvas
            myView.invalidate(); 
            return true; 

        }


    }


}
```

But when i try to handle the onTouchevent from the main activity doesn't work and the strange is that it can't read a simple variable(x,y)!!!
i can't understand why this happened,it seems it can red them only if it's in a View!!!

```
public class dragndrop extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       private ColorBall[] colorballs = new ColorBall[3]; // array that holds the balls
       private static final String TAG="MyTAG";
       DrawView myView;
       private int balID = 0; // variable to know what ball is being dragged
       int X;
       int Y;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Point point1 = new Point();
            point1.x = 50;
            point1.y = 20;
            Point point2 = new Point();
            point2.x = 100;
            point2.y = 20;
            Point point3 = new Point();
            point3.x = 150;
            point3.y = 20;


            // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
            colorballs[0] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_groen, point1);
            colorballs[1] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_rood, point2);
            colorballs[2] = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_blauw, point3);
            myView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }


 // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

        X = (int)event.getX(); 
        Y = (int)event.getY(); 

        switch (eventaction ) { 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on a ball
            balID = 0;
            for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                Log.d(TAG,"inside action down inside for coords:"+X+" coords: "+Y);
                Log.d(TAG,"ball coords:"+ball.getX()+" coords: "+ball.getY());

                int x =X;
                int y =Y;
                Log.d(TAG,"lalalalalala"+x+" coords: "+y);



                if (x > ball.getX() && x < ball.getX()+50 && y > ball.getY() && y < ball.getY()+50){//if (X > ball.getX() && X < ball.getX()+50 && Y > ball.getY() && Y < ball.getY()+50){
            Log.d(TAG,"inside ball coords!!:"+ball.getX()+" coords: "+ball.getY());
                    balID = ball.getID();


                    break;
                }
              }

             break; 


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
            // move the balls the same as the finger
            if (balID > 0) {
                colorballs[balID-1].setX(X-25);
                colorballs[balID-1].setY(Y-25);
            }

            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

             break; 
        } 
        // redraw the canvas
        myView.invalidate(); 
        return true; 

    }




    public class DrawView extends View {


        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true); //necessary for getting the touch events

            // setting the start point for the balls


        }

        // the method that draws the balls
        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);     //if you want another background color       

            //draw the balls on the canvas
            for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
              }

        }


    }


}
```

Anyone who knows why?

Yes @bigstones the onTouchevent is working,it captures all the actions,the problem is that if i have the ontouchevent code inside the activity the variables X,Y seems not to work althought that they have a value and i can print it(or log)what i am saying is tested,i've tried and change all the values from the if() statement(getX,getY)to integers and it didn't work only for X,Y.....check the code again please!
thanks!

Comment: As per references, `Activity.onTouchEvent()` is called only if none of the views consume an event. Maybe that leaving your view focusable makes it "eat" all the events? Does `Activity.onTouchEvent()` get called? (please add @bigstones in your answer so I get a notice)

Comment: Next time format your code correctly and try not to post your entire code and make us go through it.

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

I found that the problem is that it was the layout that should be registering some sort of listner so I did this:

I added this code to my Main clas:

```
private OnClickListener previewListener = new OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.err.println("I've been clicked");
    }
};
```

And the this line to the onCreate method:

```
previewLayout.setOnClickListener(previewListener);
```

And it worked!

Comment: I think you may be seeing a side-effect of adding a click listener which is that this implies `setClickable(true)`.  Rather than adding a listener that doesn't do anything useful, just call `setClickable()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed you moved the `onTouch` outside of the `DrawView`. Since you're trying to handle touch events, you need to set up a `onTouchListener` but not the `onClickListener`.